# Why Google app(Youtube, Gmail, Docs, Drive) icons are showing in "Show applications" menu?

Tags: google-chrome, icons, 22.04, appmenu, gmail

[image: Screenshot of show applications menu]

When I click on the icons it redirects to the chrome website of the app. For example for gmail app it opens mail.google.com on chrome.I saw the URL had a parameter that said "web-application". I tried looking all the suggested questions but either they don't answer my question or the answer doesn't apply to my version 22.04.

1. Why are google icons here ?
2. which of these can I safely remove and how ?

I am a new Ubuntu user please be kind. If you want me to delete the question because it is a duplicate then point me to the link of the question and I will delete this question, please don't downvote.

screenshot of chrome-extensions:

[image: screenshot of chrome-extensions]

Comment: Did you configure your Google account and link it to your Ubuntu system during installation? This may be the reason why the icons are there.

Comment: Yes.I deleted the account but that didn't change any of the icons. Now the Google account is not connected anymore. Still the icons are present. What do I do now ?

Comment: There must be something else. I've been using Google in online account for years and never had those apparently "web apps".

Comment: You mentioned these icons open a page in Chrome. They could have been added by Chrome. At least in Windows, you can create such shortcut by selecting More tools -> Create shortcut from the Chrome menu. Maybe you accidentally did this or some Chrome extension did this automatically? I don't know, however, how to delete them.

Comment: I don't think it is the extensions, I added the screenshot, please check.

Answer (score 1):

So I found the solution :

1. goto chrome:///apps
2. remove all web apps
   That's it.